# Normal of a triangular mesh

Tags: mesh, undocumented

I know the function `` Region`Mesh`MeshCellNormals[] ``, which evaluates the knot normal. I couldn't find documentation to this function which probably averages the normals of the neighboring mesh elements.

Does someone know how the averaging works? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing it with

```
R = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]]
```

and

```
R = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Triceratops"}, "MeshRegion"]
```

it looks like Mathematica takes the normals of each triangle adjacent to a given vertex and returns the normalization of their arithmetic mean.

Often a different averaging is used: Take the normals of the triangles and avarage them per *area*; i.e. take the area normals of each triangle (the cross product of two edge vectors; beware to use consistent orientations), add all the area normals of all the triangles around a vertex and normalize the result. A nice feature of these normals is that they coincide with the $L^2$-gradient of the enclosed-volume functional (for closed, oriented surfaces). In view of the Steiner formula, these normals are often considered to be "the right discretization" of surface normals. Moreover, they behave a bit better when dealing with meshes of triangles with severely differing size.

However, in view of FEM, all these normals are equally good (or equally bad), i.e. they have error $O(h)$ which is to big to use them for a consistent definition of a discrete second fundamental form - just in case your question should point into that direction.

Comment: And just to make sure: FEM does *not* make use of normals - ever.

Comment: Oh, you made the 10K mark. Well done.

Comment: @user21 Thank's!

Comment: @user21 Well, if one would like to apply FEM to curvature functionals of surfaces (e.g. thin plate energy), then the second fundamental form (the derivative of the normal vector field along the surface) is a major contribution. Applied to piecewise-linear surfaces, this does _sometimes_ leads to consistent results - and nobody can tell why. I humbly link to [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06469) (look only at the images, the rest is quite abstract and not related to approximation theory).

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: Thank you for the detailed answer, which describes some kind of  arithmetic  averaging. A different approach would be a harmonic averaging using the inverse areas. The background of my question  was the comparison of these two approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the paper, I'll have a look. I did not mean to say that you can not use normals in FEM but that for the FEM as implemented in Mathematica no normals are ever computed. If the normals are O(h) accurate then that would locally spoil any higher order FEM scheme. The normals in FEM (not MeshRegion) are used for grouping boundaries.

Comment: Do you happen to have a notebook that accompanies the paper?

Comment: @user21 Sorry for answering so late. I _really_ considered to assemble a notebook for you. The issue is that there is an enormous library behind (comprehending an own mesh data type with several caching mechanisms and tools for computing and assembling derivatives -- things are _really_ nonlinear here -- and even tools for building these tools and so on) and I do not have the time to single out the necessary parts and to put them into a single nb.

Comment: @user21 What I can say is that the energy minimized in the paper writes as `Flatten[A[x].x].Flatten[(1/LumpedAreas[x]).A[x].x]` where `x` is the $n \times 3$ matrix of the mesh coordinates of the surface and `A[x]` is $n \times n$ stiffness matrix of the Laplace-Beltrami operator of the surface. (As you can image, one of the major issues for computing a gradient was to differentiate `A[x]` with respect to `x` in an efficient way.)

Comment: @user21 This does not involve the surface normals explicitly but `1/LumpedAreas[x]).A[x].x` has much of a flavor of a trace of the derivative of the normal vector field (some people call that the divergence of the normal field). So, using piecewise linear surfaces leads to a nonconforming Ritz-Galerkin scheme. Still, the results are pretty plausible and this discrete energy (and its friends) are frequently used in geometry processing.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, don't worry about that notebook. I appreciate your effort. Thanks also for the synopsis of the important part. This is worthwhile knowing about.